# WAMP MYSQL or MYSQL service on clients side?

Tags: mysql, .net, database, wamp

We have designed an application using .NET framework. There is a client application and a server application. The client applications, webpages, android/ iphone applications fetch data from the server using the WCF service.

My issue here is that some of the data that can be set by the user on the application is being saved on the server but cannot does not reflect on the client side once the application is restarted, we have designed the application in such a way that every change on the client side will be reflected on the server side, this is done to make this a cloud based application.

Some of the settings changed or value input on the client side is updating on the server successfully but does noes reflect on the client machines using the direct MYSQL service. However there are absolutely no issues while using WAMP as the MYSQL service, i.e the clients using the WAMP server can see the changes made. We have tried matching the versions and also have tried new and old versions of the standalone MYSQL. Firewall settings all seem fine. Since we prefer to install the standalone MYSQL over WAMP on our customers machines, it would be great if you could shed some light on the possible issues. Is there any difference in the initial config of MYSQL and the default config of WAMP MYSQL.

Hence if there is any thing in particular to note or tweak in this regards it will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going to be hard to give advice, without knowing exactly what you have done to troubleshoot this issue.  You say "some" data is not being updated on the server.  That implies that the MySQL servers works and all clients are able to connect to it, but that some queries don't run. Does this seem to fit with your observations?  If so, what are the queries that are not running? What is common to them (are they all on one table - which might indicated a table problem)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get a really good answer to your question, because the term "WAMP" does not refer to a specific package, but rather any package that includes Windows versions of Apache, MySQL and PHP (and sometimes Perl instead of or in addition to PHP). See this link for a list of some of the available packages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Those packages come with different standard configurations for MySQL. Since you didn't say which WAMP package (and version) you were using, there is no way of knowing in what way their standard configuration differs from a plain MySQL installation (where the version is also important)

Have you tried just running a `diff` on the respective config files?